# Dynamically Change the Style of Control in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have styles defined for various controls viz. textboxes,combobox,datepickers,etc.. in my application. The resources needed in these styles are present in other styles and all styles are there in ResourceDictionary.

I want to change the background color of these controls to yellow on basis of some configuration settings.

I am thinking to use attached properties and make use of them with styles and set the background color. But not sure how to implement it.

Please suggest if any other approach.

Thanks,

Abdi

Comment: IF you have the property in your VM such as BackgroundColor. your style can bind to it `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}" />`When you add the style, insead of Static resource use DynamicResource. `Style={DynamicResource MyStyle}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution:

In your **view**:

Call your window like `'myForm'` or whatever:

I use in this case some radiobuttons. Each of them with an associated color You would adapt this to your requirements.

```
<UniformGrid Columns="0"  
             x:Name="_skinChanger" 
             Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="200">
    <RadioButton x:Name="BlueSkin"
                Content="Blue Skin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="131" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="None"
                Content="No Skin"
                IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="87" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="RedSkin"
                Content="Red Skin" Margin="0,0,0,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="109" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="GreenSkin"
                Content="Green Skin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="109" />
</UniformGrid>
```

The elements you want to change the style should use dynamic resource:

...

```
Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}"
```

...

Inside the **constructor of your window *for example***...

```
Loaded += RuntimeSkinning_Loaded;
```

Then define the event in your class.

```
void RuntimeSkinning_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // this is my uniformgrid where the radiobuttons are placed. I add a handled for
    // the checkedevent. 
    _skinChanger.AddHandler(RadioButton.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnSkinChanged));
}

private void OnSkinChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string name = (e.OriginalSource as RadioButton).Name;
    _registerForm.Resources.Clear();
    _registerForm.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

    if (name == "None") return;

    ResourceDictionary skin =
            Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/myproject;component/Skins/" + name + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
    _registerForm.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(skin);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```